# Exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, excel-2003

I am exporting to Excel using C# and I get this error on some records.

```
The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data
```

From googling it I saw it has to do with the size limitation, but I couldn't find a workaround. Any ideas?

Requested Code:

```
string lFilename = Leads.xls";
string lDistributorFolder = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Portals\\0\\Distributors\\" + _currentUser.UserID.ToString() + "\\";
string lTemplateFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Templates"];
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(lDistributorFolder);

File.Copy(lTemplateFolder + lFilename, lDistributorFolder + lFilename, true);
string lConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + lDistributorFolder + "\\" + lFilename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
DbProviderFactory lFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
int lSequence = 0;

using (DbConnection lConnection = lFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    lConnection.ConnectionString = lConnectionString;
    lConnection.Open();

foreach (GridDataItem lItem in grdLeadList.Items)
  {
    lSequence++;

    using (DbCommand lCommand = lConnection.CreateCommand())
      {
           lCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [ColderLeads$] ";
           lCommand.CommandText += "(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21) ";
           lCommand.CommandText += "VALUES(";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lSequence.ToString() + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gLeadNumber].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gSource].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gAccountName].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gCreatedOn].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gContactFullName].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gPriority].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gStreet1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gStreet2].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gZIP].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gCity].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + lItem.Cells[_gState].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
           lCommand.CommandText += ")";
           lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      }

     lConnection.Close();
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to export, as well as the data element on which it fails?

Comment: `I am exporting to Excel using C#` - you forgot to show the C# in your question.

Comment: @M.Babcock, unexplained downvote? Is there something not clear about the first two comments? What more explanation do you need? P.S. I didn't downvote but completely agree with the person who did. That's like saying to a mechanic: my car broke down and ask him why without bringing the car. And that's even worse: you ask him to fix your car without bringing the broken car (I suppose the OP is asking us to fix his code).

Comment: Excel 2003. I don't have that many columns or rows, just a lot of text in one column.

Comment: @M.Babcock: I downvoted for the the reasons stated in the first two comments; hence why I upvoted the first comment. Once Justin adds the necessary information, I will definitely remove my down vote.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Justin didn't ask for us to fix his code (which is more than I can say for most of the people who *deserve* to be downvoted), he asked how to address a common error. His original question was more analogous to, my car won't start because the engine won't turn over. There was enough information to theorize a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Excel 2003? If so, there is a limitation on the size of the Excel Worksheet. It is 65,536 rows by 256 columns. See the following [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx) for more info.

There is also a limitation on the Column Width. This is 255 characters. Try trimming all your fields in C# before exporting it to Excel. What you can also do is when the workbook has reached the maximum row length, create another Worksheet.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have many columns or rows. Just one column can have a paragraph of text and that seems to be too large.

Comment: @Justin does the paragraph have any carriage returns in it? Try stripping out the data to a raw string without any formatting.